# roots of the polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

For the following polynomial function $f(x) =28x^4 - 8x^3 -36x^2 + 112x -144$ complete the two items below:

1. factor the polynomial completely
2. find all the zeroes

What I have done so far is calculated the value of the function at $x=-1, x=0, x=1, x=2,x=-2$ which is

- $f(-2)=0$
- $f(-1) =-32$
- $f(0)=-144$
- $f(1)=-48$
- $f(2)=320$

so i know one root is $x=-2$
i know the other root would be between $1$ and $2$ as the sign of $f(x)$ changes from $x=1$ to $x=2$. How to find this root? And also other two roots?

Comment: cancel the common factor $4$

Comment: x= 4  is not a factor of this..

Comment: @AayushGupta  The number $4$ is a factor of each coefficient.

Comment: yeah, got it, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After division by $4(x+2)$, we find
$$7x^3-16x^2+23x-18.$$
Check if the above polynomial has a rational root $x=\pm \frac{m}{n}$ with $m,n\in\mathbb{N}^+$ where $m$ divides $18$ and $n$ divides $7$ (see the [Rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)). Among the possible values 
$$\pm 18/7, \pm 9/7, \pm 2/7, \pm 1/7,\pm 18, \pm 9, \pm 2, \pm 1$$
try first with $9/7$ which is between $1$ and $2$.

Comment: I deleted my answer; you is real nice $\to +1$.

Comment: @Robert Z how do i do it? can you please elaborate?

Comment: @AayushGupta Note that 7 is a prime, so there aren't many possibilities...

Comment: @RobertZ yeah , when you say "Check if the above polynomial has a rational root x=±m/n  where m divides 18 and n divides 7." is this some kind of identity?

Comment: @AayushGupta This is a property of polynomials with integer coefficients https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Comment: @AayushGupta Any more doubts?

Comment: @RobertZ no, I am good now, your explanations were very precise and up to the point.Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

and another factor is $$x^2-x+2$$

Comment: how did you reach this factor?

Comment: dividing by $$x+4$$ and $$7x-9$$

Comment: where did 7x-9 come from?

Comment: since $\frac{9}{7}$ is a root of your polynomial

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response guys, so here is the answer
$f(x) = 4(x+2)(7x-9)(x^2- x + 2)$
and roots are
$x= -2$ , $x=9/7$ , $x= (1+ \sqrt{7}i)/2$ , $x=(1- \sqrt{7}i)/2$